gate voltage on PMOS transistor and on and off condition


is it correct what I wrote about pmos?

I'm not sure what you mean by "magnitude", or "changes", and I don't know what \$V_{in}\$ is, so it's difficult to say whether you are correct or not. Here's a derivation of \$V_{GS,Q1}\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{GS,Q1} &= V_{GQ1} - V_S \\ \\
&= V_{GQ1} - V_{DD} \\ \\
&= - V_{R1} \\ \\
&= - (V_{DD} - V_G) \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}
\end{aligned}
$$
If \$R_1=R_2\$ this simplifies to:
$$ V_{GS,Q1} = -\frac{1}{2}(V_{DD} - V_G) $$
If that agrees with your reasoning, then yes, what you said is correct. You said it very ambiguously, though.
